# Some questions about Docker Hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am fairly new to using Docker and I went to Docker Hub to select a base image, but I have some questions.  In particular, I want to use a non-alpine amazoncorretto:latest, and am wondering:

- If I use "amazoncorretto:latest" in a Dockerfile, e.g.:

  FROM amazoncorretto:latest

is there a way to find out what specific version actually is used at runtime?  For example can I use "exec" on the running container and find out exactly which image/version is being used?  I am asking because where I work, we have to get the specific version pre-approved.

- I noticed that in Docker hub (e.g.: https://hub.docker.com/_/amazoncorretto?tab=tags) for each tag, e.g., the "amazoncorretto:latest", it shows 2 images, one without a "v8" and the other with a "v8".  What does that "v8" mean?
- Also, some tags have "al2" in the tag.  What does that "al2" mean?

Thanks, and sorry for all the really newbie questions, and thanks in advance!

Jim

Comment: tags are abitrary. You can name them as you want. In that sense v8 and al2 dont mean anything. You can use docker inspect to see the hash of the image. However, I am voting to close as the question lacks focused / contains multiple questions.

Comment: If you run `docker history amazoncorretto:latest`, in the 3rd line you'll see something like `version=1.8.0_332.b08-1`. That's the version the Corretto people set when they built the image.

Comment: I hear what you all are saying, and I tried to explain why I was looking for what I was asking about, but probably not clearly enough. We originally were using jdk-alpine as base image, but were getting UnknownHostExceptions, so after testing, I found that we had to use a non-alpine jdk base image and amazoncorretto:latest seemed to work w/o exceptions.  BUT the program I work on REQUIRES we specify the SPECIFIC base image for approval, otherwise we are not allowed use it, so I was looking for which I needed to specify; NOTE they are not asking for the JDK version, rather the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a Docker question: how would you normally tell what version of Correto you're using? It looks as if `java -version` provides this information, so you can just run that command in a container:

```
$ docker run --rm docker.io/amazoncorretto:latest java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_332"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.332.08.1 (build 1.8.0_332-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.332.08.1 (build 25.332-b08, mixed mode)
```

---

It is possible to figure out some of this from the available Docker tags. If you look at the information for the `latest` tag, it shows, it shows that the `linux/amd64` version of the image has digest `1395e022da6d`. If we look at the list of available tags, we see the same digest for the tag `8u332`.

It's fairly common -- but by no means universal! -- for the `latest` tag to be an alternative name for a version-specific tag.